# Finding constant for a quadratic function (AHSME)

Tags: contest-math, quadratics

first off, sorry for asking such a trivial question.
I am going over the book Intermediate algebra from the AoPS series, and can't seem to figure out why my solution is wrong.

Function $\textit{f(x)} = \frac{cx}{2x+3}$ satisfies $(f\circ f)(x)=x$ for $x=\mathbb{R}\setminus \left\{ -\frac{3}{2}\right\} $.

Find $c$.

To me it seems quite obvious that expecting $c = 0 \rightarrow (f\circ f)(x) = \frac{c^{2}x}{2cx+6x+9} = \frac{x}{6x+9}$, thus making it undefined at $x = -\frac{3}{2}$
However, it appears that the correct answer is $c = -3$ https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1980_AHSME_Problems/Problem_14

Thanks for your help.

P.S. I am sorry, for any mistakes made in the expressions.

Comment: If $c=0$, then $f(x)=0$, so $ff(x)=0$ and is defined for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Set your expression for $ff(x)$ in terms of $c$ equal to $x$ and you can proceed from there.